# find $n-$th differential coefficient of $y = (\arctan x)^2$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, power-series

Let $y = (\arctan x)^2$,

$$
y' = 2 \arctan x \cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
By Leibniz Formula,
$$
(1+x^2)y^{(n)} + (n-1)\cdot(2x)y^{(n-1)} + (n-1)(n-2)\cdot2y^{(n-2)}  = 2(\arctan x)^{(n-1)}
$$
Let $x=0$,
$$
y^{(n)} + (n-1)(n-2)\cdot2y^{(n-2)} = 2(\arctan x)^{(n-1)}|_{x=0}
$$
And we know, for $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$,
$$
(\arctan x)^{(2k)}|_{x=0} = 0\\
(\arctan x)^{(2k+1)}|_{x=0} = (-1)^k(2k)!
$$

Then I have no idea. I am finding for the solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) can be applied directly (to $fg$ with $f=g=\arctan$).

Equivalently, the power series
$$
\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}x^{2n-1}
$$
is squared by taking the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series) with itself:
$$
\color{blue}{(\arctan x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}a_n x^{2n},\quad
a_n=}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k-1)(2n-2k+1)}.
$$
Since $\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2n-2k+1}=\frac{2n}{(2k-1)(2n-2k+1)}$, the expression for $a_n$ simplifies to
$$
a_n=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2n-2k+1}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}}.
$$
*Using $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ ([harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)), one may write $a_n=\frac1n\left(H_{2n}-\frac12 H_n\right)$.*